# Get an empty Vcard Qrcode wit qrcode gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qr-code

I'm using rqrcode gem and would like to get a vcard data.

The png is generated, but without any data

```
def qrcode
    qrcode_data = %{BEGIN:VCARD
      VERSION:4.0
      N:#{@participant.nom};#{@participant.prenom}
      ORG:#{@participant.entreprise}
      EMAIL:#{@participant.email}
      TEL;type=PREF:#{@participant.tel}
      END:VCARD}

    qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new(qrcode_data)
    png = qrcode.as_png(size: 200)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.png { send_data(png, type: 'image/png', disposition: 'inline') }
    end
  end
```